# Storing variables and equation results in dictionary in Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, dictionary, for-loop

I have an equation with three variables. I use three for loops to calculate it.

I would like to turn the results of the equation into dictionary form.

For example,

```
import numpy as np

equation = np.ones((2, 3, 4))
for Ls in range(2):
    for ts in range(3):
        for angle in range(4):
            L = (Ls+1) * 10
            t = ts * 5
            theta_i = 18 * angle
            equation[Ls][ts][angle] = L * t + theta_i

print(equation)


[[[  0.  18.  36.  54.]
  [ 50.  68.  86. 104.]
  [100. 118. 136. 154.]]
 [[  0.  18.  36.  54.]
  [100. 118. 136. 154.]
  [200. 218. 236. 254.]]]
```

I would like the results to become something like this:

```
dict = {Ls: 0, ts: 0, angle: 0, equation: 0}
dict = {Ls: 0, ts: 0, angle: 1, equation: 18}
dict = {Ls: 0, ts: 0, angle: 2, equation: 36}
dict = {Ls: 0, ts: 0, angle: 3, equation: 54}
dict = {Ls: 0, ts: 1, angle: 0, equation: 50}
dict = {Ls: 0, ts: 1, angle: 1, equation: 68}
dict = {Ls: 0, ts: 1, angle: 2, equation: 86}
dict = {Ls: 0, ts: 1, angle: 3, equation: 104}
dict = {Ls: 0, ts: 2, angle: 0, equation: 100}
dict = {Ls: 0, ts: 2, angle: 1, equation: 118}
dict = {Ls: 0, ts: 2, angle: 2, equation: 136}
dict = {Ls: 0, ts: 2, angle: 3, equation: 154}

dict = {Ls: 1, ts: 0, angle: 0, equation: 0}
dict = {Ls: 1, ts: 0, angle: 1, equation: 18}
dict = {Ls: 1, ts: 0, angle: 2, equation: 36}
dict = {Ls: 1, ts: 0, angle: 3, equation: 54}
dict = {Ls: 1, ts: 1, angle: 0, equation: 100}
dict = {Ls: 1, ts: 1, angle: 1, equation: 118}
dict = {Ls: 1, ts: 1, angle: 2, equation: 136}
dict = {Ls: 1, ts: 1, angle: 3, equation: 154}
dict = {Ls: 1, ts: 2, angle: 0, equation: 200}
dict = {Ls: 1, ts: 2, angle: 1, equation: 218}
dict = {Ls: 1, ts: 2, angle: 2, equation: 236}
dict = {Ls: 1, ts: 2, angle: 3, equation: 254}
```

I try to search online but can't find any similar example. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
import numpy as np
from collections import defaultdict
import json
equation = np.ones((2, 3, 4))
result_dict = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(dict))
for Ls in range(2):
    for ts in range(3):
        for angle in range(4):
            L = (Ls+1) * 10
            t = ts * 5
            theta_i = 18 * angle
            result_dict[Ls][ts][angle] = L * t + theta_i

#export to file
with open("result.json","w") as file:
    json.dump(result_dict, file)

#import from file
result_dict = json.load(open("result.json"))

#query result
def get_equation(result_dict, Ls, ts, angle):
    return result_dict[str(Ls)][str(ts)][str(angle)]

print(get_equation(result_dict=result_dict, Ls=0, ts=1, angle=1))
#68
```

Comment: Is it possible to save the result as a file? So that in the future I can import the file, and call something like print(['Ls': 0, 'ts': 0, 'angle': 0]) and get the output: 'equation': 0

Answer (score 0):

You can add :

```
print("dict = [Ls: {}, ts: {}, angle: {}, equation: {}]".format(Ls, ts, angle, L * t + theta_i))
```

at the end of the for-loops body (straight after `equation[Ls][ts][angle] = L * t + theta_i` and still in the loops)

Is that what you want ?

Comment: Is it possible to save the result as a file? So that in the future I can import the file, and call something like print(dict=['Ls': 0, 'ts': 0, 'angle': 0]) and get the output: 'equation': 0

Comment: Of course, write this in your code:
`answer = "dict = [Ls: {}, ts: {}, angle: {}, equation: {}]".format(Ls, ts, angle, L * t + theta_i)` then
`file=open('storage_file.txt', w+)` and finally
`file.write(answer)`

You've just created a text file with the answer in it. (doc : [link](https://www.codespeedy.com/how-to-create-a-text-file-in-python/) )